# strcpy from a struct char* to another struct char* - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I seem to have a problem with copying a char array from at struct to another char array in another struct. Im getting a segmentation fault, and i think it has something to do with allocating memory for my char array in the struct. But could somebody please identify the exact point that is causing a core dumped.

```
struct match 
{
  char *day;
  char *date;
  char *hour;
  char *home_side;
  char *visitors;
  int home_result;
  int visit_result;
  int spectators;
  int rounds;
  int result;
};

struct team
{
  char *name;
  int victory_visit;
  int victory_home;
  int home_visitors;
};

typedef struct match match;
typedef struct team team;
```

Then i have the function that fills the struct called match

```
    void scan_matches(match *all_matches)
{
  int i = 0, counter = 1, round_number = 1;;
  FILE *ifp = fopen("kampe.txt","r");
  char line[LINE_MAX];

  while(fscanf(ifp," %[^\n]", line) == 1)
  {
    int thousand, hundreds;
    sscanf(line,"%s %s %s %s - %s %d - %d %d.%d", &all_matches[i].day, &all_matches[i].date, &all_matches[i].hour, &all_matches[i].home_side, &all_matches[i].visitors,
      &all_matches[i].home_result, &all_matches[i].visit_result, &thousand, &hundreds);
    all_matches[i].spectators = ((thousand * 1000) + hundreds);
    round_number = create_rounds(all_matches, counter, i, round_number);
    counter++;
    i++;
  }
  fclose(ifp);
}
```

after that is the function that causes me trouble. A function where i want to copy the char *homeside form the match struct, to the char *name in the team struct.

```
void load_teams(match *all_matches, team *all_teams)
{
  int i, j = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    strcpy(all_teams[j],all_matches[i].home_side);
    j++;
    strcpy(all_teams[j],all_matches[i].home_side);
    j++;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n",all_teams[j].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not pass `all_teams[j]`, which has type `team` to the first argument of `strcpy()`, which expects `char*`. It should be `all_teams[j].name`?

Comment: are you allocating them at all?

Comment: Are you sure you allocated enough memory to each parameters? Posting [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is helpful.

Comment: "*But could somebody please identify the exact point that is causing a core dumped.*" you could do this yourself: Compile with  symbols (option `-g` for GCC), run the program using GDB, after it crashed enter the GDB command `backtrace` and see the call stack including source file names and line numbers where to crash occured. Use the GDB command `list` to list the very line causing the the crash.

Comment: It may save you a great deal of trouble to declare the `struct` members as `char` *arrays* of sufficient size to handle the largest allowed data, instead of as `char` pointers.  Each `struct` would consume more memory than the data strictly require, but if there are any remotely reasonable bounds on the required sizes then the extra memory use is probably a more than fair trade for the ease-of-use advantages.

Comment: A `struct char` is disallowed by the standard as far as I can tell. Just a matter of wording your title.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` will not allocate memory, it will try to write to an already allocated buffer (for all the %s arguments you used).

Since those pointers are garbage (never allocated), `memcpy` or `strcpy` will fail with a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
struct match 
{
  char *day;
  //...
```

has *pointers* to characters, but does not have the *storage* to store these characters. So when you read them they are "stored" by sscanf at some undetermined place, which probably is not yours, so the operating system aborts your program.

Either declare them as arrays of characters, or have sscanf read them into a buffer of sufficient size, then determine its length and then use `malloc` to allocate the storage and copy the buffer to that storage.

Answer (score 0):

all_matches and all_teams are not declared as array

> void load_teams(match *all_matches, team *all_teams)

so you can't use this:

> strcpy(all_teams[j],all_matches[i].home_side);
>   j++;
>   strcpy(all_teams[j],all_matches[i].home_side);
>   j++;

You function should declared like this:

```
void load_teams(match **all_matches, team **all_teams)
```

the same remark for:

```
void scan_matches(match **all_matches)
```